# How to count rows that have common field/value combination?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to work out how many times a record has had its shared data with other records in the database with a table structure this:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  RecordID  |  Field  |  Value    |
+============+=========+===========+
|  1         |  phone  | 11111111  | << Person 1
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  1         |  email  | 1@abc.com | << Person 1
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  2         |  phone  | 22222222  | << Person 1
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  2         |  email  | 1@abc.com | << Person 1
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  3         |  phone  | 33333333  | << Person 2
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  3         |  email  | 3@abc.com | << Person 2
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  4         |  phone  | 44444444  | << Person 1
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  4         |  email  | 4@abc.com | << Person 1
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  5         |  phone  | 11111111  | << Person 1
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  5         |  email  | 4@abc.com | << Person 1
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  6         |  phone  | 55555555  | << Person 3
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  6         |  email  | 5@abc.com | << Person 3
+------------+---------+-----------+
```

We are use phone OR email to identify a person/record. This means if they share either phone or email they are linked together.

The result would be something like this:

```
+-----------+---------+
| RecordID  |  Count  |
+===========+=========+
|  1        |  4      | << Person 1
+-----------+---------+
|  2        |  4      | << Person 1
+-----------+---------+
|  3        |  1      | << Person 2
+-----------+---------+
|  4        |  4      | << Person 1
+-----------+---------+
|  5        |  4      | << Person 1
+-----------+---------+
|  6        |  1      | << Person 3
+-----------+---------+
```

The `count` represents the number of times that the RecordID has shared data with other records.

Is this even possible to do with SQL? What would be the query to work this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT  RecordID, COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY RecordID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses, but this will only count the RecordID's, not the relationship to the other records

Comment: @Shawon FYI to make a better answer, don't just say "try this" but explain what you changed and why